# Getting reference of window / form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am converting some winform code to wpf, in the winform code i have the following lines

```
frmStartup parentfrm = (frmStartup)Application.OpenForms["frmstartup"];
if (parentfrm != null)
{
    db = parentfrm.db;
}
```

I need to convert this into WPF, there is a Window called windowSplash that is designed to replace this, however changing frmstartup to windowSplash doesn't work.

Comment: Think how you can rewrite the code so you don't have to do this. WPF does not support OpenForms, since it's Windows Forms specific.

Comment: @Alex it would involve instigating the objects every time meaning adding 60+ lines of code to each window, hence the reason it is done like this

Comment: Can't the objects be stored outside the form? This is the point of WPF, separating logic from GUI. The solutions provided here by others may work but you should think about the consequences of following this route.

Comment: @Alex the items are classes designed to integrate with Lync, MySQL and a number of other systems.  The splash screen initiates the connections and then each window/form in the app references this so the setup doesn't need to be done again.  How would you achieve this?

Comment: one of the ways is to use Application.Startup event for initialization and storing settings in your own class. Perhaps, not the most elegant solution, but at least you don't have to rely on Window references. Here is an example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
WindowStartup parentfrm = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<WindowStartup>().FirstOrDefault();
if (parentfrm != null)
{
   db = parentfrm.db;
}
```

This would find the first window matching the type though. If that doesn't work for you (you may have several windows of the same type), The best way to do this would be making your windows implement some kind of interface. Off my head and just as an example:

```
public interface IDbWindow
{
   string Key { get; }
   DbContext Db { get; }
}
```

Then make your `Window` implement `IDbWindow`, something like (in the XAML code-behind):

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window, IDbWindow
{
   public string Key { get; private set; }
   public DbContext Db { get; private set; }

   public MyWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      Key = "ThisIsTheWindowImLookingFor"; // this key might be set somewhere else, or be passed in the constructor, or whatever
      Db = new MyDbContext(); // for example
   }
}
```

And then you can search the windows for the specific `Key`, instead of the window type:

```
IDbWindow parentfrm = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<IDbWindow>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "ThisIsTheWindowImLookingFor");
if (parentfrm != null)
{
  db = parentfrm.Db;
}
```

I'd further add that you shouldn't really depend on `Application.Current.Windows`, and you should be managing your own collection (of `IDbWindow` in this case, but it could be called `IDbHolder`), adding and removing as necessary. This would remove your dependency on the objects containing `Db` being actual Windows (which doesn't make logical sense, they could be whatever).

Comment: No definition for "OfType" System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<WindowStartup>.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Did you add `using System.Linq;` on top of your class?

Comment: bah it had the ; missing
'Enumerable.OfType<TResult>(IEnumerable)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context 
var parentfrm = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<CINTRA_2016.windowSplash>.FirstOrDefault();
        if (parentfrm != null)
        {
            db = parentfrm.db;
        }

Comment: ugh even I missed it, having a bad coding day!

Comment: I've added further tips so you are not constrainted to the type of the window. Maybe unneeded in your case, but just for correctness

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the open `Windows` in the application using [`Application.Current.Windows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows(v=vs.110).aspx) and check for its name or type:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
    if (window is TypeOfWindow)
    {
        // do what you want

        break;
    }
}
```